# Integration JIRA and GitHub concerns: is connection safe and private?

Tags: github, jira

I see there are two option for JIRA and GitHub integration: DVCS Connector or one of Marketplace Apps.

Are there any security/privacy reasons (data leakage), why one shouldn't connect the two, using above mentioned methods?

Answer (score -1):

Seems generally secure. But of course your decision depends on what you put in your Jira and GitHub repos

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course, I'm interested in the case where my data is sensitive.